# C++ convert string to typedef OR istream overload

Tags: c++, class, templates, typedef, operator-keyword

I have a class template, which is -- among other things -- supposed to overload istream so it accepts the user's input and adds (pushes) it into a vector, which holds type T elements.

```
    friend istream &operator>> (istream &in, Set<T> &s)
    {
        int ctr = 0;
        string tmp;
        T val;
        while (true) {
            cout << "\tElement #" << ctr + 1 << ": ";
            getline (in, tmp);
            if (tmp == "\0") break;
            // MISSING CODE HERE: "Convert" tmp into val
            s.add(val);
            ctr = s.size();
        }
        return in;
    }
```

This works fine with `Set<string>`, but I need to find a way to make it function with any primitive data type, too, i.e. `Set<integer>`, for example.

I tried doing

```
stringstream(tmp) >> val
```

but that then doesn't work with `Set<string>`.

I guess the input needs to be read in as string; how, then, do I cast the input string into T type to pass it to the .add() function?

Comment: Please show all of your code, not just this subset.  It's a little unclear what exactly is going on.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `stringstream` object (created from `tmp`) to extract the correct value if it is not a string.  Note you will have to overwrite `operator>>` for `ostream` if you need more than just the built-in types (e.g. `int`)

Alternatively, you can define overloads of a `convert()` function for each `T` you encounter to provide proper conversion from the string `tmp` to the required type.  The proper overload (if exists) will be selected based on your template parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `boost::lexical_cast` to convert strings to other types lexicographically.

```
template<class T>
friend istream &operator>> (istream &in, Set<T> &s) {
    int ctr = 0;
    string tmp;
    T val;
    while (true) {
        cout << "\tElement #" << ctr + 1 << ": ";
        getline (in, tmp);
        if (tmp == "\0") break;
        val = boost::lexical_cast<T>(tmp);
        s.add(val);
        ctr = s.size();
    }
    return in;
}
```

Alternatively, you can use `std::istringstream`.

```
std::istringstream sstream(tmp);
sstream >> val;
```

---

Note that `boost::lexical_cast` throws an exception if the cast wasn't successful, and `std::istringstream` **does not** (you need to check this manually).

Comment: THANK YOU! THANK YOU!! THANK YOU!!!  I didn't want to chance Boost, because I'm not sure it's available on my school computers, so I went with the "alternatively."  Man, if you were a pretty girl, I'd give you a big kiss.  Heck, I might just do that anyway! :D  Seriously, I can NOT believe I didn't try that.

Comment: @Michael If this answer helped you, you may accept it by clicking the gray checkmark next to it, so people in the future know where to look.

Answer (score 0):

There a few issues in the code that you may like to address:

```
getline (in, tmp);
```

That need to check the return value:

```
if(!getline (in, tmp))
    // handle end-of-file or read failure
// read okay, tmp contains the read line
```

Next:

```
if (tmp == "\0") break;
```

It's not very common to have embedded zeros in text files. May be this piece is trying to detect the end-of-file condition, which should be handled by checking the return value of `getline` or `if(in)` statement.

```
stringstream(tmp) >> val;
```

That creates a temporary string stream and tries to invoke `operator>>` on it. Well, there are two kinds of `operator>>` for `std::istream`:

- `std::istream` member functions that accept temporary (r-values) and l-values `std::istream` object
- free standing ones that take `std::istream` by reference to non-const, which don't accept r-values. (In C++11 it can accept it also as `std::istream&&` allowing for r-values).

Hence, the above statement can only stream into built-in types for which there is a member `operator>>` in `std::istream`.

So, that statement can be replaced with:

```
std::istringstream ss(tmp);
ss >> val;
```

That would need to have error handling again to check whether entire `str` was parsed into `val`, so, as others have said here, it's easier to use `boost::lexical_cast<>` that does error checking for you:

```
val = boost::lexical_cast<T>(tmp);
```

If you don't insist on reading the full line, rather reading white-space separated tokens, then the loop can look like this:

```
template<class T>
friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &in, Set<T> &s) {
    int ctr;
    T val;
    while(in >> val) {
        ctr = s.size();
        std::cout << "\tElement #" << ctr + 1 << ": ";
        s.add(val);
    }
    // end-of-file or parsing failure
    if(!in.eof()) {
        // handle failuer to parse or read error
    }
}
```